# Counting $k$-tuples from non-distinct collection of elements.

Tags: combinatorics

Assume that we have a collection of objects $\{n_1,n_1,n_2,n_2,...,n_k,n_k\}$. In how many ways can we construct a set $\{n_1,...,n_k\}$ consisting of distinct $k$-tuples?

Answer (score 1):

You must choose one from each two-element multiset $\{n_i, n_i\}$, and you must choose $k$ times. Thus there are $2^k$ ways in total.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Thus similarly, if we want for instance a collection where two of the $n_i$'s are equal only, then we have $2^{k-1}$ ways right?

Comment: I don’t quite understand what you mean. If only two $n_i$’s are equal there are only two ways to select. If only two are non-equal then we would have $2^{k-1}$ ways.

Comment: I mean the number of ways, a collection like $\{n_1,...,n_j,n_j,....,n_k\}$ where all but the $n_j$'s are distinct.

Comment: @user430191 Then clearly there are only two ways, since only $n_j$ can alter.

Comment: Perhaps I don't phrase that correctly; say that we choose from the beginning that both $n_j$'s are in the collection and we want all the other $k-2$ elements being distinct. In how many ways can we construct such a set this time?

Comment: And I was thinking that similarly, we left with $k-1$ tuples of elements to fill these $k-2$ positions up, thus similarly we must have $2^{k-1}$ ways to do so. Is that correct?